# Reshape data frame by groups

Tags: r

I have a data frame where each observation is apart of a large case, where every 20 rows a new case begins, ie rows 1:20 are case 1 and 21:40 are case two. I want to analyze each case as a whole so I want to reshape the data based on the variable `CaseId` so that every case is represented in a single observation without losing any data. I tried this code.

```
train_clean <- train %>%
  group_by(CaseId) %>%
  summarise_all(function(train) paste0(train, collapse = "_")) %>%
  cSplit(names(.)[-1], '_')
```

This partially worked, where every case was represented in a single row but in created exactly double the number of columns for every row, such that instead of variable X having X1 ... X20 where every observation from the raw data is represented in a single row for the case, I get X1 to x40 but with X21: X40 being empty. This happens to every variable in the data, is there something I need to tweak in my code to get it to work how I'd like.

This is a basic example of what I want to do but on a larger scale.

```
       X         CaseID
1  73.91 20170907000118
2  74.67 20170907000118
3  71.07 20170907000139
4  66.46 20170907000139
```

```
           CaseID    X1    X2
1  20170907000118 73.91 74.67
2  20170907000139 71.07 66.46
```

I appreciate any help I can get, thank you

Comment: Add a variable that counts by 20 to have as the cases, then use that as the `key` argument in a call to `tidyr::spread` or `names_from` in `tidyr::pivot_wider`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, here is a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
#read in sample data
DT <- fread("X         CaseID
73.91 20170907000118
74.67 20170907000118
71.07 20170907000139
66.46 20170907000139")
#create rownubers by CaseID-group
DT[, id := rowid( CaseID )]
#cast to desired wide format
dcast( DT, CaseID ~ paste0("X", id), value.var = "X")

#            CaseID    X1    X2
# 1: 20170907000118 73.91 74.67
# 2: 20170907000139 71.07 66.46
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` after creating a sequence column grouped by 'CaseID'

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%  
  group_by(CaseID = as.character(CaseID)) %>%
  mutate(rn = str_c("X", row_number())) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = X)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  CaseID            X1    X2
#  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
#1 20170907000118  73.9  74.7
#2 20170907000139  71.1  66.5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c(73.91, 74.67, 71.07, 66.46), CaseID = c(20170907000118, 
20170907000118, 20170907000139, 20170907000139)), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
library(tidyr)
train_clean <- train %>%
     spread(key= caseID, value  = X)
```

This should work as you wish so long as there are symmetrical numbers of X observations in in all the separate cases.

Edit: If you do have missing values you can set `fill =NA` or any other value to occupy the columns where there is not another X for that case when the other cases have one.